# Which power covers summonable armor?

Tags: powers, marvel-faserip

I'm currently in the process of running a round with the old marvel-super-heroes rules (yepp not the 2012 version but the 'ancient' one).

The players are able to choose powers and one came up with a nice idea that his character can summon a supernatural knights armor that protects him from harm.

Now reading through the powers in the lists I'm just not sure which is better fitting rulewise.

- Defense - Body armor(Artificial)
- Physical enhancement - Armor skin

Or something else entirely?

As a bit more details about the armor here:
The Armor itself is so that it can be summoned and does provide protection to its wearer (damage reduction). Also it can be unsummoned again with ease. The shape itself is fixated  while when summoned the amor is just "created" and ceases to exist when unsummoned (or taken off).

Comment: We talking FASERIP, here?

Comment: no marvel super heroes. FASERIP is a "fan remade" of the system. In some areas better in others worse.

Comment: I'm confused. I was speaking of the, far as I know, original rpg: used faserip for the stats and had those brightly coloured charts on the back, the success/fail tables.

Comment: @user30200 Ah I'm talking about marvel super heroes. I think the system itself was also called faserip time and again but there is also the FASERIP system  itself (http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/177913/Faserip) it is a "neo-clone game of super heroes, based on a classic 1980s role-playing game."  (and that 1980s game is marvel super heroes)

Comment: Yeah, the version of the Marvel RPG I'm speaking of was lovingly nicknamed FASERIP by fans due to the stats spelling that out. I actually don't recall the proper title of the books, I've been calling it that for so many decades. (one google search later) Seems to be the "Marvel Super Heroes Role Playing Game" (MSHRPG), published by TSR. Here's the wiki on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_(role-playing_game) Even mentions that it was referred to as the "FASERIP system". ^^

Comment: @user30200 Yepp and because of that one ripoff I always say that I mean the marvel one so that its sure that ppl understand what I'm meaning (as I had a few misunderstandings before there with ppl meaning the ripoff while I meant marvel and vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

The power to summon a suit of armor resembles MCr1/**Artifact Creation**, which includes this special allowance: "When creating the character, the player can choose to specialize in creating a single copy of one specific item, like a suit of armor or a costume" (64). It's easy enough for the Judge to rule that the armor disappears when removed, but this isn't specifically covered by the rules.

However, the power Artifact Creation *is* a bit excessive for the desired effect when all's said and done. What the player *wants* seems to be a way to create a costume instantaneously and get some defense. I'd suggest using the temporary version of the aforementioned power P1/**Armor Skin** but adding another entry for summoned armor exactly as the question describes.

Answer (score 1):

Body Transformation could be tweaked to cover your desire with a +2cs limitation (the one material limit), and some clever fluff text. As a bonus, you get your instant on and off effect built in.

Pick a tough material covered by your power rank, and it counts as body armor to boot.

*edit*: I just noticed that the Alter Ego power would also fit perfectly for an insta-summon/dismiss on the armor... a long as you don't mind being a normal (or mostly normal, see possible limitations) when it's not summoned.